# Android and Java 8's default method

Tags: java, android

Can I use Java 8's **default** Interface feature in Android project ?

In my Android project I want to have interface with default method implementation. Can I achieve it using the Java 8's **default** method concept ?

Comment: Set the Java target to 1.8 and use it?

Comment: java 8 is not supported in android yet AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any features of Java 8 that weren't available in Java 7 will not work.